# Morse index for height function potential on $S^2$ from its Hessian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, supersymmetry, ground-state

I was reading David Tong's notes on [Supersymmetric Quantum Mechanics](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/susyqm.html). In the third chapter, page no. 86, he gives an example of ground state counting using Morse Theory over $S^2$. The potential $h$ is identified with the height function,

$$h=z=\cos\theta\tag{1}$$

Critical points $x=X$ of this potential can be found using the Morse function,

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}(X)=0\,\forall\, i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\tag{2}$$

And the Morse index can be found using the Hessian of the potential, which is defined as,

$$\mu(X)=\text{no. of negative eigenvalue of }\partial_i\partial_j h(X)\tag{3}$$

Now for the potential defined at $(1)$ on $S^2$ the critical points will be at $\theta=0,\pi$. Tong proceeds to identify the ground state at $\theta=0$ with $2$-form while $\theta=\pi$ with $0$-form. Of course heuristically this should be true given that in the Morse inequality, which says,

$$m_p\geq b_p\tag{4}$$

where $m_p$ is the number of critical points for a $p$-form ground state ($\mu(X)=p$) and $b_p$ is the $p$-th Betti number, the equality holds when all the ground states are at $E=0$ (thus supersymmetric). This tells us that for any $h\to \lambda h,\,\lambda\gg 1$, the ground states will be localized at the critical points and also that due to $b_0=b_2=1,b_1=0$ for $S^2$ we will have a $2$-form and a $0$-form ground states.

I would like to see this derived from the Hessian definition of the Morse index in $(3)$. For that I took the covariant derivative instead of partial derivative, taking the embedded metric of the $S^2$ and the related Christoffel symbols. With that I'm getting the following matrices for the two critical points,

$$\nabla_i\nabla_jh(\theta=\pi)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\tag{5}$$

and,

$$\nabla_i\nabla_jh(\theta=0)=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\tag{6}$$

which gives the correct result for the $0$-form at $\theta=\pi$ but not for the $2$-form at $\theta=0$. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or perhaps if there is any calculation mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The polar coordinate system $(\theta,\phi)$ is singular at the critical points (=the north and south pole). Use instead a coordinate system that is regular at the critical points, e.g. $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks this worked.